# MySQL Query not returning all rows according to echo ouput

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a MySQL query, I really can't figure this out. 
The database is like this: 
ID = 1,2,3,4  |  Currency = CAD, USD, GBP, EUR 
Output from the following code is:   
1 1 
1 1 
C C 
C C

```
 $Curr = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `Currency` FROM `currencies` WHERE `IsActive`=1"));

 foreach($Curr as $CurrElem){ 
     echo $CurrElem['Currency'] . '      ' . $CurrElem['ID'] . '<br />';
 }
```

Comment: does the table have IsAvtive field too ? what does the table structure look like ?

Comment: You will need to show us what isActive is set to for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array will only ever return one row so you need to loop it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `Currency` FROM `currencies` WHERE `IsActive`=1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one other semi-related question, if I wanted a mysql_fetch_assoc() for the ID and Currency. How would I refer to it? I thought it was this: $rowCurr["Key"] and $rowCurr["Value"], but that seems incorrect.

Comment: Using my code sample it would just be $row['Currency'] and $row['ID'] inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Its the mysql_fetch_array that is causing the problems...you are pulling the first item....what you want is..

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

Above is just to show syntax : more @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php